# Scrollbar appearing like in Azure management portal

Tags: jquery, azure, scrollbar

I am building a web Application following the newset 'metro' (or I'd rather say 'modern') guidelines for Win8 Apps, I'd like to ask if anybody knows how to implement a scrollbar (vertical/horizontal) which appears only when the user hovers on the overflowed div, coming from the side (or the bottom for horizontal scrolling) and having a custom style. A perfect example of this can be found @ http://manage.windowsazure.com. Every overflowing div gets this 'div' on mouseover, which appears from the side and has a scrollbar, which I find very clean and unobtrusive. I have searched various 'custom scrollbar' plugins and scripts but none seem to be like the one on Windows Azure Management Portal.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I use [jQuery nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html) with good results.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I noticed that the Azure Portal is using a CSS style to achieve this effect: `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;`. I can verify that it works in IE 11 and it [does appear to work in Windows 8 Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx).

As far as the web usage, it's an ms- vendor prefix so they're certainly providing some sort of JS fallback on the Azure Portal website. Hope that helps!